# Can't display the category name wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, categories

I want to display the category name in a menu (navbar of bootstrap). 
Here is my code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light flex-md-column flex-row align-items-start py-3">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="flex-md-column flex-row navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="test1" href="#"><?php echo get_cat_name(4); ?></a>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
      </div>
```

displays nothing, 4 is my id for the category "Agenda".

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `<?php print_r(get_categories()); ?>` Use this and send me result

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it displays : 


    > Array ( [7] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 1 [name] => Non classé [slug] => non-classe [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 1 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 319 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 1 [category_count] => 319 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Non classé [category_nicename] => non-classe [category_parent] => 0 ) [8] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 3 [name] => Offres d'emploi [slug] => offres-demploi [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => ...

Comment: I don't precise it but i want to display subcategory names, maybe it's different ?

Comment: Try this `<?php echo get_the_category_by_ID(4); ?>`

Comment: I have this : 

    Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in C:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\child_theme\archive.php on line 43

Comment: What version of WP you use?

Comment: Wordpress version : 4.9.5

Comment: Go to wp-includes/category.php and check function `get_cat_name` it should be like `function get_cat_name( $cat_id ) {
 $cat_id = (int) $cat_id;
 $category = get_term( $cat_id, 'category' );
 if ( ! $category || is_wp_error( $category ) )
  return '';
 return $category->name;
}`

Comment: Also check if your category `Agenda` has id 4, you can do it by function: `get_cat_ID( $cat_name );`

Comment: Oh you save my life, bro, agenda has id 15. But i don't understand because in the back office, i saw "identity = 4" in wordpress

Comment: No problem ) To check category id without this function just go to the catogories list hover name of category, id you want to know, than look at link at left bottom, find get request element named 'tag_ID' - its value is category id

Comment: got it, thanks for your time, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light flex-md-column flex-row align-items-start py-3">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="flex-md-column flex-row navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="test1" href="#"><?php echo get_the_category(4); ?></a>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
      </div>
```